# Jenkins slave connection using SSH

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Ubuntu master machine and windows 10 slave machine

I need to connect slave machine(windows machine) from master machine(ubuntu) using SSH Connection

Followed the below link

https://devopscube.com/setup-slaves-on-jenkins-2/

attached node details and global credential configuration:

[image: attached node details and global credential configuration]

Faced the below issue while launching. please help me on this

`[05/08/17 06:26:10] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 172.16.108.233:22. Connection timed out (Connection timed out) SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection timed out (Connection timed out)". java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to
172.16.108.233:22   at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:818)     at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:687)     at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:587)     at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1198)   at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:724)    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:719)    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)     at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.establishConnection(TransportManager.java:354)   at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.initialize(TransportManager.java:467)    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:758)     ... 9 more [05/08/17 06:28:21] Launch failed - cleaning up connection [05/08/17 06:28:21] [SSH] Connection closed.`

**Note: In Slave machine Git only installed(Jenkins not installed)**

Answer (score 2):

In the key configuration you should put the private key not the public key
And in the slave machine you don't need to install Jenkins

Comment: You may also need to put the public key into the slave machine's authorized_keys file.

Comment: Changed private key in key configuration and put the public key  file into slave machine authorized_keys file. but still the same issue occurs

Comment: Are you sure about the user name and the passphrase that you use in your configuration!!

Comment: user name is one of the user of the slave machine(christopher.hirudaya)and the passphrase given in master machine is the same which is used in slave machine while generating key pairs

Comment: just in case try to generate a new ssh key and try with it !!